# Python find fixed payment for compound monthly interest

Tags: python, debugging, finance

I was asked to write a program that calculates the minimum fixed monthly payment needed in order pay off a credit card balance within 12 months. By a fixed monthly payment, I mean a single number which does not change each month, but instead is a constant amount that will be paid each month. The fixed payment must be a multiple of 10, so a negative ending balance at the end of the year is fine.

```
balance = 3329; annualInterestRate = 0.2
month=1
monthlyInterest = (annualInterestRate)/12.0
totbalance = balance*(pow(1+monthlyInterest, 12))
fixedPayment = 10
endbalance = totbalance
while (endbalance - (fixedPayment * 12)) >= 0:
    if (endbalance - (fixedPayment * 12)) == 0:
        break
    else:
        fixedPayment+=10
print "Lowest Payment: ", fixedPayment
```

The fixed monthly payment I have is constantly greater than what the correct answer is, so I think it might be a problem with my loop, or my compound interest formula. However I checked online and I think I have expressed the formula in the correct way. 
I know it has been asked before, but I would just like to understand what is wrong with this approach. Thanks!

Comment: Making a payment should decrease the amount of interest charged in the next month.

Comment: There is a tag for finance !

Answer (score 1):

There is a [formula](http://www.hughcalc.org/formula.php) for calculating exactly what you are looking for.  Using this is much cleaner than looping through the possible monthly payments, since this does not scale with the balance.  You can then round up to the nearest increment of 10.